# Giving every submitted form a different I'd in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, admin

I got a problem when trying to submit the review form. Below are the two issues

1. When l try to send the form without `pk=1` it returns an error below

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /submit _review/7/ 
get() returned more than are Action Review--it returned 6!
```

2. When I try to send the form when `pk=1`, it works and the review form is sent to the Admin. **But the following below nor work**

**It only changes the  review form with an id=1**

**My Expectations and Needs**

I would like to have a form submitted and it gets the **new id not being fixed like `pk=1`**, but getting a **new id everytime and every form sent or submitted**

**#Action/views.py**

```
def submit_review(request,game_id):
    url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            reviews = ActionReview.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id, game_name__id=game_id, pk=1)
            form = Game_ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=reviews)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank you! , Your review has been Updated Successfully.')
            return redirect(url)
        except ActionReview.DoesNotExist:
            form =Game_ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                data=ActionReview()
                data.subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
                data.stars = form.cleaned_data['stars']
                data.content = form.cleaned_data['content']
                data.game_id=game_id
                data.user__id=request.user.id
                data.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Thank you! , Your review has been Added Successfully.')
                return redirect(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.get` method in django tries to returns 1 row, it is not supposed to return more than one

If you want to have multiple results use `.filter`

```py
 reviews = ActionReview.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id, game_name__id=game_id) # Returns everything matching this logic
```

In your try block

```
try:
    reviews = ActionReview.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id, game_name__id=game_id)
    for instance in reviews:
        form = Game_ReviewForm(request.POST, instance=instance)  
        form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Thank you! , Your review has been Updated Successfully.')
    return redirect(url)
```

Comment: When I try on solution it returns an error again that `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'.`

Comment: It's because form can handle only one instance, you have to use a loop to save multiple instances using form

Comment: How? Help me with a live example on how to do it

Comment: I tried it but it duplicated the form Three times in the, yet l want the submitted message to appear once, and it also hide the recent sent reviews , making them not to appear in the template